# How to buy NFTs from my smart contract with custom ERC20 token?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, dapps, erc-721, erc-20-approve

i want to launch a NFT genesis collection for all the holders of the previous collection.
The previous collection gave the holders a ERC20 Token airdropped. So the holders have the custom ERC20 Token.

Now... i want they can buy the new collection with that custom ERC20 token, and not with ETHER.

I dont know how to do this.

I was trying to but i cannot find the way of doing it.

This is the ERC721A part of the contract involved in the process of buying with the custom erc20 token.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.9 <0.9.0;

import 'erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol';

contract ERC721A is ERC721A, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

  using Strings for uint256;

  bytes32 public merkleRoot;
  mapping(address => bool) public whitelistClaimed;

  string public uriPrefix = '';
  string public uriSuffix = '.json';
  string public hiddenMetadataUri;
  
  uint256 public cost;
  uint256 public maxSupply;
  uint256 public maxMintAmountPerTx;

  bool public paused = true;
  bool public whitelistMintEnabled = false;
  bool public revealed = false;

  address public a1;
  address public a2;

  address tokenAddress;


  constructor(
    address _tokenAddress,
    string memory _tokenName,
    string memory _tokenSymbol,
    uint256 _cost,
    uint256 _maxSupply,
    uint256 _maxMintAmountPerTx,
    string memory _hiddenMetadataUri
  ) ERC721A(_tokenName, _tokenSymbol) {
    tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    setCost(_cost);
    maxSupply = _maxSupply;
    setMaxMintAmountPerTx(_maxMintAmountPerTx);
    setHiddenMetadataUri(_hiddenMetadataUri);
  }

    modifier callerIsUser() {
        require(tx.origin == msg.sender, "The caller is another contract");
        _;
    }

  modifier mintCompliance(uint256 _mintAmount) {
    require(_mintAmount > 0 && _mintAmount <= maxMintAmountPerTx, 'Invalid mint amount!');
    require(totalSupply() + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, 'Max supply exceeded!');
    _;
  }

  modifier mintPriceCompliance(uint256 _mintAmount) {
    require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, 'Insufficient funds!');
    _;
  }

     function GetUserTokenBalance() public view returns(uint256){ 
       return tokenAddress.balanceOf(msg.sender);// balancdOf function is already declared in ERC20 token function
   }

    function Approvetokens(uint256 _tokenamount) public returns(bool){
       tokenAddress.approve(address(this), _tokenamount);
       return true;
   }

     function GetAllowance() public view returns(uint256){
       return tokenAddress.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
   }

    function mint(uint256 _tokenamount,uint256 _mintAmount) public returns(bool) {
    require(_tokenamount > GetAllowance(), "Please approve tokens before transferring");
    ERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenamount);
    _safeMint(_msgSender(), _mintAmount);
    return true;
    }

    function GetContractTokenBalance() public onlyOwner view returns(uint256){
    return token.balanceOf(address(this));
   }
```

and this is the ERC20 Custom token i want to use

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;


import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract tokenA is ERC20 {
    address public deployer; //to save adress of the deployer
    
    constructor() ERC20('Token', 'token') { //called by the deployer (once)
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000000 * 10 ** 10); //mint/create tokens - we have created 100000000000*10^18 tokens
        deployer = msg.sender;  //set the deployer
    }

    //total supply is fixed no more can be created ever

    function burn (uint amount) external {  //remove tokens by sending then to a zero address
        _burn(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

I repeat, i just want to people buy the NFTs with the custom token i created.

I hope somebody can help me.

I will be forever grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You must change the `mint` function. If it is callable by the end user, why would you want it to take as a parameter `_tokenamount`? You only need to know the amount of NFT tokens the user would like to mint. Then, you should initially verify whether he has enough tokens to do so. You calculate the tokenAmount by multiplying the amount of NFT tokens purchased by their cost.  Then you transfer this amount to the contract and you finally mint the tokens.

This function shouldn't be called from within the contract, thus make it external. External functions are more gas efficient compared to public ones.

```
function mint(uint256 _amount) external {
    address sender = _msgSender();

    require(_amount * cost >= IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(sender));
    IERC20(tokenAddress).safeTransferFrom(sender, address(this), _amount * cost);
    _safeMint(_amount);
}
```